# Truecrypt device not recognized under windows 7

Tags: truecrypt

I have an usb drive encrypted with truecrypt. Until a couple weeks or so i could mount the drive with truecrypt easily, but now trucrypt does not display the usb device anymore, so i cannot mount it. Also, the device manager from windows 7 does not recognize the usb hdd anymore. I can mount the partition under linux with truecrypt, so it's not a drive problem. Any ideas how i can get win7 / truecrypt to recognize the usb hdd device again?